Why is there a one pixel offset in the canvas?
I'm drawing 16x16 pixel squares on a 64x64 canvas and using CSS to scale them. However, the right corner of the square is misaligned. Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening and how to fix it?
I'm using CSS with "image rendering: pixelated" and "image rendering: sharp edges". In the Google Chrome browser on Windows


const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)"
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

function drawSquare(positionY, positionX) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(positionX * 16, positionY * 16, 16, 16);
}

drawSquare(1, 1)
drawSquare(2, 1)
        body {
          margin: 0;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          height: 100vh;
          background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }
        
        canvas {
          width: 100vmin;
          height: 100vmin;
          max-width: 100%;
          max-height: 100%;
          image-rendering: pixelated;
          image-rendering: crisp-edges;
        }
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="64" height="64"></canvas>
</body>



If for some reason the problem does not appear on your screen, here is an image of the problem.
enter image description here

I don't see a misalignment in your example. I'm not saying it's not there, just that your example isn't showing it clearly. I'm using Firefox Beta for Android, if that's relevant.

I'm going to modify the post and attach a photo so that anyone who doesn't see it knows what I'm talking about.

I revisited this on my desktop PC, also with Firefox. There is definitely no alignment problem with either Firefox for Windows or Firefox for Android. This implies that the problem is a bug in Chrome, and possibly will also occur in Edge.

Try using transform: scale( <integer here> ) + transform-origin: top left; instead of width and height.
Width and height sometimes cause fractional scaling and result in misaligned pixels. while transform would use integer scaling which preserves alignment and sharp edges
so try something like this
canvas {
      transform: scale(10); /* You might want do have it scale dynamically through your script rather than here.*/
      image-rendering: pixelated; 
      image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    }


Thank you very much, that worked!
The only thing is that the canvas would no longer be responsive, but that fixes the pixel problem :D
